# Arredondar Casa decimal

Tags: python

Caros senhores estou com duvida de arredondamento em python.

Sei, por exemplo, que se eu tiver uma variável assim:

```
n=2.23445
print (f'o valor de n é {n:.2f})
```

vai imprimir 2.23

Mas, no caso de uma lista?

```
lista [2.23453, 2.34543, 2.457755]
```

Como faço para arredondar os elementos da lista?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar list comprehension. Neste caso a resposta seria...

```
lista = [2.23453, 2.34543, 2.457755]
lista_1 = [round(item, 2) for item in lista]
print(lista_1)
```

Neste caso, os elementos da lista foram arredondados com `duas casas decimais`.

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir os elementos arredondados basta colocar o nome do vetor e o índice do elemento.

**Por exemplo**:

```
lista = [2.23453, 2.34543, 2.457755]

print (f'O valor do elemento de índice 0 da lista é: {lista[0]:.2f}')
```

Para imprimir todos os valores da lista arredondados podemos ultilizar o loop for:

```
for x in range(len(lista)):
    print(f'o valor do elemento de índice {x} é {lista[x]:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Depende do que você quer dizer com "*arredondar os elementos da lista*".

Se você quer **só** imprimir os valores arredondados, faça um *loop* pelos elementos e imprima-os:

```
for n in lista:
    print(f'{n:.2f}')
```

Nesse caso, como a ideia é **somente** imprimir, não precisaria criar outra lista, como sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467783/112052) (só faria sentido criar outra lista se você fosse usá-la para outras coisas posteriormente, senão estará criando-a à toa).

Claro que dá para fazer umas "firulas":

```
for i, n in enumerate(lista, start=1):
    print(f'{i}º elemento = {n:.2f}')
```

Que imprime:

```
1º elemento = 2.23
2º elemento = 2.35
3º elemento = 2.46
```

Mas enfim, uma vez percorrendo a lista, você pode fazer o que quiser com cada elemento.

---

Mas se "*arredondar os elementos da lista*" significa criar outra lista com os valores arredondados, aí você pode fazer:

```
rounded = [ round(n, 2) for n in lista ]
```

Eu usei [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) em vez da *f-string*, porque se eu fizer `f'{n:.2f}'` o resultado será uma string. Mas se você quer uma lista de números, deve usar `round`. Claro que ao imprimir não fará diferença porque os valores serão mostrados do mesmo jeito, mas se for usar esta lista para algo depois (como por exemplo fazer cálculos), melhor já criá-la com números em vez de strings.

Lembrando que nesse caso, como os números já foram arredondados, basta imprimi-los diretamente:

```
for n in rounded:
    print(n)
```

---

Por fim (apesar de não ser o foco da pergunta), vale ler a [documentação sobre as limitações de números de ponto flutuante](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues), para entender, entre outras coisas, porque `round(2.675, 2)` é `2.67` e não `2.68`.